# How can I find a value between a range, when percentage is giving?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algorithms

I have a problem where I need to find a value (i.e. `x`) between the range 80 and 200.

The value of `x` will depend on a giving percentage value. For example, if the percentage is 75 %, then `x` should be a value that is closer but not exceeding 200 "Well unless the percentage is over 100 %." And if the giving percentage is 20, then `x` should be closer but not less than 80.

So when the percentage is 100 % then `x` is 200. And when the percentage is 0 % then `x` is 80.

What algorithm could I use to find a value of `x`?

I tried to do something like this

1. Convert the percent into decimal (Y)
2. (Y * min) / max

But that gives me a number that is less than the min.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a order-preserving linear map from the interval $[0,100]$ to $[80,200]$. Generally, the order-preserving map $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ is given by
$$f(x) = c + \tfrac{x-a}{b-a}\cdot(d-c)$$
So your map is $$f(x) =\underbrace{80}_{\textrm{start}} +\underbrace{\tfrac{x}{100}}_{\textrm{fraction of the way}}\cdot \underbrace{120}_{\textrm{full length}} = 80 + 1.2x$$

Comment: Thank you for this answer. So what would be the value of x in this case if the target is 75 %? Is f(x) .75 so 0.75 = 80 + 1.2x?

Comment: @MikeA : $f(75)=80+\tfrac{75}{100}\cdot 120 = 170$

Comment: @MikeA : I've added some explanatory comments to the formula, have a look

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean). If the percentage of the way from $80$ to $200$ is $p$ then the number you're looking for is
$$
200p + 80(1-p).
$$

You can see that this gives the right answer when $p=1$ or $0$ or $1/2$.

The formula even makes sense when $p > 1$ ("more than $100\%$") or less than $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The only sense I can make of this question is you want $f:[0,100] \to [80,200]$ so that $f(0) = 80$, $f(100) = 200$ and that: $f(t)$ is proportionally between $f(0)$ and $f(100)$ as $t$ is proportional between $0$ and $100$.

That last garbled weird bit, can be translated into math as:

$\frac {f(t) - f(0)}{f(100) - f(0)} = \frac t{100}$

or $f(t) = t*[f(100) - f(0)] + f(0)$

Which can be thought of as:  $f(0) = 80$ is the starting point.  $f(100)=200$ is the ending point.  $f(100) - f(0)=120$ is the total distance.  $t*[f(100) - f(0)]=t*120$ is the net distance done.  And $f(t) = t*[f(100) - f(0)] + f(0)= t*120 + 80$ is the total distance done.

So $f(t\%) = t\%[200-80] + 80 = t\%*120 + 80$

So, say $17\% \to 17\%(120) + 80 =100.4$. And $80\% \to 80\%*120 + 80 =  176$ etc.